# Force 8x8 blocks partitions in HEVC HM reference software

Tags: codec, hevc

I would like to force the HEVC reference software, HM Encoder Version [16.15], to use a fixed partition size of 8x8 pixels both for transform and motion compensation. Can I do that and what are the encoder configuration parameters to change? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest manually changing the RDCost of all other sizes to a large number. For example you can multiply them by 1000.

This can easily be done inside the `predInterSearch()` function in the `TEncSearch.cpp` file.